# Silverlight 5 orange background after splash screen?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I created a .NET application using Silverlight 4. On Silverlight 4, I never added any splash screen or anything of that kind. After a while, Silverlight 5 came out, and I tried to integrate everything I did from SL4 to SL5. Everything works fine, except for a small detail. The problem is after the splash screen appears, a random background of orange comes out for a split second before it shows my login page. Did anybody experience the same kind of problem before? Is this an explained phenomenon? Thanks for all help.

Comment: we could probably help you better if you posted some code

Comment: I can't even post any code. I haven't added anything yet, still it shows. I don't see any of my code affecting this.

Comment: Having the same problem as Nathan.  I believe he is referencing this control: http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/TiledBackgroundImage/.  Even going to that page, you can duplicate the bug he is talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it now. It's a problem with tiled background dll when I upgraded from SL4 to SL5. Maybe the DLL wasn't upgraded. Anyways, I just set the height of the tiled background to 0, then gave it back it's height after. That solved my problems.